# Is there a way I can put T4 directives inside comment brackets?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, syntax, t4

Consider the following code:

```
<#@ assembly name="$(Path)\Custom.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(OtherPath)\Custom.dll" #>
```

I'd like to do something in the likes of:

```
<#@ assembly name="$(Path)\Custom.dll" #>
<!--<#@ assembly name="$(OtherPath)\Custom.dll" #>-->
```

Is there a syntax that allows me to put directives in comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so because T4 uses regex to parse out the code and directives from the files when it compiles them.  The regex statement it uses is searching for <#@ and #> lines and considers everything else to be part of the template.